# Use Remmina to RDP into home Remote Desktop Gateway Server

Tags: server, windows, remote, rdp, remmina

I have Windows Server 2012 R2 running at home which is hosting "Anywhere Access" and acting as a Remote Desktop Gateway Server. I have tried using Remmina to RDP into this gateway but I can't seem to find a successful combination of parameters to get in. I'll try to explain the scenario below...

Gateway Server: mydomain.remotewebaccess.com
Client: MyClient1
Domain: mydomain.local
User: User
Password: Password

So, by default, Anywhere Access allows me to remote into any Win7/8 PC on my home network through it's web interface. I click a PC, it initiates an RDP connection with the selected PC. Port 3389 doesn't have to be opened on my router, but 80, 443, 500, 1701, and 1723 must be open for Anywhere Access to work.

Within Remmina, I tried the following:

Server: mydomain.remotewebaccess.com
User Name: mydomain\User
Password: Password
Domain: mydomain.local
Security: (tried NLA, TLS, RDP, Negotiate with no luck)
Client name: MyClient1

This combination of settings isn't working and I'm not too sure what it takes to make Remmina play nicely with an RDP Gateway that doesn't use port 3389. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you ever get this to work? I have the same problem.

Comment: I have the same problem - On windows I can launch the `.rdp` file and in Ubuntu it will try to connect to the `hostname.local` that is the desired hostname.

Answer (score 4):

I run the following script to log in to a remote server through RD-gateway, current freerdp git-master works rather well.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Get the password once since the same password are used for RD-gateway and remote server
PW=$(zenity --password)

# RDP to remote server remote1.server.com through RD-gateway rdg.server.com
xfreerdp /g:rdg.server.com /gu:mysuername /gd:MYDOMAIN /gp:$PW /v:remote1.server.com +compression /u:myusername /p:$PW /d:MYDOMAIN +clipboard /size:1548x846 /network:broadband /bpp:32 /cert-ignore
```

Information on compiling FreeRDP can be found here:
https://github.com/FreeRDP/FreeRDP/wiki/Compilation

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 64bit which has FreeRDP 1.0.2. When was the Remote Gateway Support implemented in FreeRDP? I cannot seem to get it working.

Comment: So I don't want to compile if I don't need to. This page looks good for compilation also: http://ifconfig.dk/freerdp/

Answer (score 3):

If you get the latest versions of FreeRDP you can do this from the commandline, but it is tricky and tends to crash randomly in my tests so I find it unusable for daily use. When it crashes I could reconnect immediately.

You can support the feature request for this improvement in remmina here: 
https://github.com/FreeRDP/Remmina/issues/347